# how to parse xml using dom parser in android?

Tags: android

here is my xml..I want to get apikey using dom parser...any help would be appreciated..thanx.

```
 <user>
    <company>My company</company>
    <access-level nil="true"/>
    <last-activity-at nil="true"/>
    <api-key>here is my api key </api-key>
    <email-address>myemail@gmail.com</email-address>
    <id type="integer">42569</id>
 </user>
```

Comment: Check out the official Android documentation on how to parse XML: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: See below link for XML Parsing using DOM Parser example with Complete Source code, may be it will help you. [XML Parsing Using DOM Parser](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-%E2%80%93-using-domparser)

Comment: I am able to parse if there are many <user> inside <users>....I mean like this  <users><user>...</user> <user>...</user> </users>

Comment: Thanx Dipak but I found the solution and posted answer below...

Comment: @OlegVaskevich That page does not show any example of using a DOM XML parser, but only mentions two SAX parsers. The OP asked for a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey friends I got the solutions as following..

```
try {

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

            NodeList assignee_ = element.getElementsByTagName("api-key");
            Element line = (Element) assignee_.item(0);
            statuses=(Utility.getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go for this link it may help you

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is);

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
                // return DOM
            return doc;
    }
```

for more info check the link..

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

i have used the parsing xml in my actual application,here is my approach

```
 public class XMLParser {
        // constructor
                public XMLParser() {

                }

                /**
                 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
                 * @param url string
                 * */
                public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
                    String xml = null;

                    try {
                        // defaultHttpClient
                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // return XML
                    return xml;
                }

                /**
                 * Getting XML DOM element
                 * @param XML string
                 * */
                public Document getDomElement(String xml){
                    Document doc = null;
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    try {

                        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                        InputSource is = new InputSource();
                            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                            doc = db.parse(is); 

                        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                            return null;
                        } catch (SAXException e) {
                            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                            return null;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                            return null;
                        }

                        return doc;
                }

                /** Getting node value
                  * @param elem element
                  */
                 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
                     Node child;
                     if( elem != null){
                         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                                     return child.getNodeValue();
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     return "";
                 }

                 /**
                  * Getting node value
                  * @param Element node
                  * @param key string
                  * */
                 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
                        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
                        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
                    }




    }
```

and in the main class i make this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> booksList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_MAG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_CATG, parser.getValue(e, KEY_CATG));
            //map.put(KEY_AUTOR, "Auteur:"+parser.getValue(e, KEY_AUTOR));
            //map.put(KEY_PRICE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRICE)+"DT");
            map.put(KEY_PRICE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRICE));

            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            booksList.add(map);
        }
```

and this my vars:

```
static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.100/vos_magazines1.xml";
static final String KEY_MAG = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id_mag";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "titre_mag";
static final String KEY_PRICE = "prix_mag";
static final String KEY_CATG = "cat_mag";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "pic_mag";
```

hope my code give helps